# How to pipe program output in an editor?

Tags: linux, editor, pipe

I have my program generating some data. It output everything on standard error.

Now I'd like to redirect the output to a newly started text editor, into the main unnamed edit window that shows at startup. I tried with vim and gedit without success.

```
myprogram | gedit
myprogram | gvim
```

Anyone knows about an X11 text editor that would support this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to redirect `stderr` of your program in to `gvim` you can do:

```
myprogram 2>&1 | gvim -
```

and in case if you want to redirect the `stdout` to the editor you can do:

```
myprogram| gvim -
```

Comment: Yes, '-' stands in many programs for STDIN/STDOUT instead of a file.

Comment: It's not even `stderr` that I want. Simply `stdout`. How is it possible I didn't though out to using file `-`! Answer is simply `myprogram | gvim -` .

Answer (score 12):

I tried this in Ubuntu 12.04, it works as desired:

```
sudo lshw | gedit &
```

On Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo lshw | gedit - &
```

*Dimitry K* added on *Jan 22 '16 at 19:00* the following

I think you still need dash after:

```
gedit sudo lshw | gedit - &
```

(tried ubuntu 14.04 and only with dash it works) –

Comment: Additional information: This is a new feature in Gedit. It was introduced in the version that came with Gnome 3.0. See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=121891 .

Comment: I think you still need dash after gedit `sudo lshw | gedit  - &` (tried ubuntu 14.04 and only with dash it works)

Answer (score 6):

To do this all in one line with any editor, create a temporary file, open it with gedit, then delete it once gedit has it open:

`echo hello > temp ; gedit temp ; sleep 1 && rm temp &`

The following works with an editor such as vim, but gedit, geany or emacs seem to be unable to open standard input or temporary files as created by <( )

`vi <( echo hello )`

`echo hello | vi -`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any editor that supports this, but redirecting to a temp file might be easier.

```
F=$(mktemp)
myprogram >$F
gedit $F
rm $F
```

Answer (score 2):

```
history | kate -i
```

my favorite editor :-)

As already said, when a program does not support such piping, the best way is to use a temporal file in the directory /tmp/ which is usually deleted at the next boot.

```
history > /tmp/bflmpsvz;mcedit /tmp/bflmpsvz
```

Answer (score 1):

[`vipe`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/moreutils/vipe.1.en.html) does this for an arbitrary `$EDITOR`, available on macOS /homebrew via `brew install moreutils`

> ```bash
> command1 | vipe | command2
> ```
>
> `vipe` allows you to run your editor in the middle of a unix pipeline and edit the data that is being piped between programs. Your editor will have the full data being piped from `command1` loaded into it, and when you close it, that data will be piped into `command2`.

> `EDITOR`: Editor to use.